# Marker is not appearing to select from and to position to calculate and draw path between two marker in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Marker is not appearing to select from and to position to calculate and draw path between two marker in google map .

I want to select two location with marker and calculate distance and draw a path between two marker after selection .But unable to selection two location with marker and unable to calculate distance.

I am unable to set from Location with marker ,set to location with marker and not able to calculate distance also .

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener{

    //Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    //From -> the first coordinate from where we need to calculate the distance
    private double fromLongitude;
    private double fromLatitude;

    //To -> the second coordinate to where we need to calculate the distance
    private double toLongitude;
    private double toLatitude;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    //Our buttons
    private Button buttonSetTo;
    private Button buttonSetFrom;
    private Button buttonCalcDistance;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleapi client
        // ATTENTION: This "addApi(AppIndex.API)"was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        buttonSetTo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetTo);
        buttonSetFrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetFrom);
        buttonCalcDistance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalcDistance);

        buttonSetTo.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSetFrom.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCalcDistance.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://net.simplifiedcoding.googlemapsdistancecalc/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(googleApiClient, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://net.simplifiedcoding.googlemapsdistancecalc/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(googleApiClient, viewAction);
    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        //Creating a location object
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }

    //Function to move the map
    private void moveMap() {
        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Adding marker to map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

        //Moving the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Animating the camera
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    public String makeURL (double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog ){
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString
                .append(Double.toString( sourcelog));
        urlString.append("&destination=");// to
        urlString
                .append(Double.toString( destlat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
        urlString.append("&key=AIzaSyB2iWnsp0TvWCrBB5AYYxG8J3Mad4q1npo");
        return urlString.toString();
    }

    private void getDirection(){
        //Getting the URL
        String url = makeURL(fromLatitude, fromLongitude, toLatitude, toLongitude);

        //Showing a dialog till we get the route
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Getting Route", "Please wait...", false, false);

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Calling the method drawPath to draw the path
                        drawPath(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        //Adding the request to request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    //The parameter is the server response
    public void drawPath(String  result) {
        //Getting both the coordinates
        LatLng from = new LatLng(fromLatitude,fromLongitude);
        LatLng to = new LatLng(toLatitude,toLongitude);

        //Calculating the distance in meters
        Double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from, to);

        //Displaying the distance
        Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(distance+" Meters"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        try {
            //Parsing json
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .addAll(list)
                            .width(20)
                            .color(Color.RED)
                            .geodesic(true)
            );


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //Clearing all the markers
        mMap.clear();
        //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));

        latitude = latLng.latitude;
        longitude = latLng.longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //Getting the coordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //Moving the map
        moveMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonSetFrom){
            fromLatitude = latitude;
            fromLongitude = longitude;
            Toast.makeText(this,"From set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(v == buttonSetTo){
            toLatitude = latitude;
            toLongitude = longitude;
            Toast.makeText(this,"To set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(v == buttonCalcDistance){
            getDirection();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.mymapapp.MapsActivity" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cc3b60a7"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSetFrom"
                android:text="Set From"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSetTo"
                android:text="Set To"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCalcDistance"
                android:text="Calc Distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for draw line between two origin and dest:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.clear();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 16);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        System.out.println("Latitude "+latitude+ " \n Longitude "+longitude);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LatLng origin = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        LatLng dest = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(destLatitude),Double.parseDouble(destLongitude));

        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);


    }

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception downloading", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";

            if(result.size()<1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                        continue;
                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(5);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }

            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(destLatitude), Double.parseDouble(destLongitude)))
                .title(getLocationStringAddress(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(destLatitude), Double.parseDouble(destLongitude))))
//                    .snippet(getLocationStringAddress(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(destLatitude), Double.parseDouble(destLongitude))))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.map_set_marker)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519076/how-to-show-navigation-between-two-lat-lng-in-google-map-in-without-intent-andro/38519185#38519185